# Get value of a method in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to develop a small application which has two forms `form1` and `authentication` form.

So when user enters SQL instance to connect to I validate that instance and on success , I redirect the user to another form.

**Here is authentication method code:**

```
public string authenticate()
{

     if ((textBox1.Text == null) )
     {
           MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All Fields!");
           return null;    
     }

     else if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
     {
          connnectionstring = "data source=" + textBox1.Text + " ;Initial Catalog =master;Integrated Security = SSPI";
          return connnectionstring;    
     }

     else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
     {
          connnectionstring = "data source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Initial Catalog =master;userid=" +textBox2.Text + ";password" +textBox3.Text;
          return connnectionstring;    
     }
     return null;
}
```

The above method gives me connection string , So in `form1` I am trying to use the connection string to get all databases in that instance.

I am just trying to print what is being returned before even checking all databases, But I am always getting null value.

Here is the way I am calling `authenticate` method in `form1`.

```
private void checkRecommendedSettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Authnetication auth = new Authnetication();
     MessageBox.Show(auth.authenticate());
}
```

But I am always getting null value, I think this is because when `form1` is called `authentication` form `TextBoxes` are having null values since they passed out of scope. But I am not able to figure out a way to get the value so far

Update:
below changes helped me solve this issue

**in authentication form:**

```
 Form1 f = new Form1(authenticate());
```

**in form1 :**

```
 public string constring { get; set; }


        public Form1(string value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            constring = value;



        }
```

Comment: I dont see where do you call authenticate().

Comment: Ooops !.sorry added now

Comment: Is authentication form modal (has OK, Cancel buttons) ?

Comment: No alex,only above code

Comment: Something is missing. There should be a way to tell when user is done entering the data: a button , keyboard key (e.g. ENTER) or something of that sort.

Comment: Hi Alex,Same method works fine and gives data when i call in same form that is authentciation form,but only i am getting blank values when calling from another form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to achieve it. Below are the following methods

1) **Constructor Overloading**

```
//Declaration of Constructor Overloading
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string value)
    {

    }
}

//Code for using constructor overloading
Form1 frm = new Form1("text to be passed to the next Form");
frm.Show();
```

2) **Public Variable**
   These Variables are initialized on the initialized of the class and can be accessed by creating an object of the class

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declaration of Static Variable
    public string Value = "";
    public Form1()
    {

    }
}

//Code for using static variable
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Value = "text to be passed to the next Form";
frm.Show();
```

3) **Static Variable** *(This method is not recommended but still is a method of achieving the goal)* 
   These Variables are initialized on the starting of the project and can be accessed anywhere in the project by writing their Parent Class Name

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declaration of Static Variable
    static string Value = "";
    public Form1()
    {

    }
}

//Code for using static variable
Form1.Value = "text to be passed to the next Form";

Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but if you are calling that `Authenticate` method in a separate form then you are right, those form field values won't be present. Rather you can pass those values into your `Form1` constructor and inturn pass those parameter to the `Authenticate` method. Below is what I am trying to say

```
Public Form1(string textbox1, string textBox2, string textBox3, bool radio1checked, bool radio2checked)
{
  //do somekind of initialization
}
```

Call the `Authenticate` method passing the parameter like

```
private void checkRecommendedSettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Authnetication auth = new Authnetication();
    MessageBox.Show(auth.authenticate(textbox1, textbox2,textbox3,radio1checked, radio2checked));
 }
```

You need to change your `Authenticate` method signature accordingly like

```
public string authenticate(string textBox1, string textBox2, string textBox3, bool radio1checked, bool radio2checked)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All Fields!");
                return null;

            }
            else if (radio1checked)
            {
                connnectionstring = "data source=" + textBox1 + " ;Initial Catalog =master;Integrated Security = SSPI";
                return connnectionstring;

            }
            else if (radio2checked)
            {
                connnectionstring = "data source=" + textBox1 + ";Initial Catalog =master;userid =" +textBox2 + ";password = " +textBox3;
                return connnectionstring;

            }
            return null;
        }
```

So while instanciating the `Form1` pass those form field data to the constructor like

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, radioButton1.Checked, radioButton2.Checked);
frm1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Parameters of authenticate() methods are modified but it is called as MessageBox.Show(auth.authenticate()).

Comment: @learningNew, that's a typo. Meant to pass those params to the method call. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I pointed it out o that It could be corrected. Commenting is better than downvoting an answer for typos.